A discrete multiple sum over strictly increasing integer sequences.
Let $l \ge 1$ and $m \ge 0$  and $k \ge l$ be integers.
Then let ${\bf A}= \left( A_\eta \right)_{\eta=1}^l$ and ${\bf B}= \left( B_\eta \right)_{\eta=1}^l$ be parameters.
We define the following multiple sum:
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak S}_{l,m}^{({\bf A},{\bf B})} (k):=
\sum\limits_{1 \le j_1 < j_2 < \cdots < j_l \le k}
\prod\limits_{\eta=0}^{l-1} (j_{\eta+1} + A_{\eta+1})^{(m+1)} (j_{\eta+1} + B_{\eta+1})^{(m)} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
This sum appears in a natural way when finding the Frobenius power series solution to a certain class of ordinary differential equations with polynomial coefficients, see this post.
We define auxiliary coefficients as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&{\mathfrak C}_l=
-\sum\limits_{\eta=1}^l \sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{(2(l-\eta)+1)m+l-\eta}
\Lambda^{(l,\eta)}_\xi \cdot (A_\eta-l+\eta)^{(m+l-\eta+2+\xi)}\\
&&\Lambda^{(l+1,\eta)}_\xi =
\sum\limits_{\xi_2=0 \vee \xi-( (2(l-\eta)+1)m+l-\eta )}^{(2m+1) \wedge \xi}
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0 \vee (\xi_2-m-1)}^m \\
&&
\left( \right. \\
&&
\left.
\Lambda^{(l,\eta)}_{\xi-\xi_2} \cdot
(B_{l+1} - A_{l+1}-m-1)^{(m-\xi_1)}
(A_{l+1} - A_\eta-(m+\xi-\xi_2)-1)^{(m+1+\xi_1-\xi_2)} \cdot \binom{m+1+\xi_1}{\xi_2} \binom{m}{\xi_1} \cdot 1_{\eta \le l} + \right.\\
&&
\left.
{\mathfrak C}_l (B_{l+1} - A_{l+1}-m-1)^{(m-\xi)} \cdot \binom{m}{\xi} \cdot 1_{\eta=l+1} \right. \\
&& \left.
\right) \cdot \frac{1}{m+l-\eta+3+\xi} \tag{2a}
\end{eqnarray}
for $l=1,2,\cdots$, $\eta=1,\cdots,l+1$ and $\xi=0,\cdots, (2(l+1-\eta)+1)m+l+1-\eta$
subject to $\Lambda^{(1,1)}_\xi = (B_1-A_1-m-1)^{(m-\xi)} \binom{m}{\xi}/(m+2+\xi) $.
We have shown that this multiple sum admits the following neat closed form expression below.
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak S}_{l,m}^{({\bf A},{\bf B})} (k) = 
\sum\limits_{\eta=1}^l \sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{(2(l-\eta)+1) m+l-\eta}
\Lambda^{(l,\eta)}_\xi \cdot
\left(
(k+A_\eta-(l-\eta))^{(m+(l-\eta+2)+\xi)}
-
(0+A_\eta-(l-\eta))^{(m+(l-\eta+2)+\xi)}
\right) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
We have derived the result by decomposing the product of Pochhammer symbols into linear combinations of single Pochhammer symbols  and then performing the sums bottom -up by using the Pascal triangle identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k+1} - \binom{n}{k+1}$.
Note:
We coefficient at the highest  order term in $(2)$ are given below:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\Lambda^{(l,1)}_{\xi_m(l)} = \frac{1}{l! (2m+2)^l} \\
\end{eqnarray}
where $\xi_m(l):= (2(l-1)+1)m+l-1$.
Proof by induction:
Fix $l$ and take the new factor in the term in the multiple sum and decompose that factor into a linear combination of upper Pochhammer symbols as follows:
\begin{equation}
(j_{l+1} + A_{l+1})^{(m_1)} (j_{l+1} + B_{l+1})^{(m_2)} 
=
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0}^{m_2} (B_{l+1}-A_{l+1}-(m_1))^{(m_2-\xi_1)} \cdot \binom{m_2}{\xi_1}
\cdot
(j_{l+1} + A_{l+1})^{(m_1+\xi_1)} \tag{3a}
\end{equation}
for integer $m_1,m_2 \ge 0$.
Now we in $(1)$ we replace $k \rightarrow j_{l+1}-1$ and multiply both sides of it by $(3)$. Then we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{1 \le j_1 < j_2 <  \cdots < j_l < j_{l+1} }
\prod\limits_{\eta=0}^l
(j_{\eta+1} + A_{\eta+1})^{(m+1)}
(j_{\eta+1} + B_{\eta+1})^{(m)}
= \\
&&
\left.
\sum\limits_{\eta=1}^l
\sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{(2(l-\eta)+1)m+l-\eta}
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0}^m
\Lambda^{(l,\eta)}_\xi \cdot
(B_{l+1}-A_{l+1}-(m+1))^{(\eta-\xi_1)} \cdot \binom{m}{\xi_1}
\cdot
\underline{\underline{
(j_{l+1} + A_\eta -(l-\eta+1))^{(m+(l-\eta+2)+\xi)}
(j_{l+1}+A_{l+1})^{(m+1+\xi_1)}}} + \right. \\
&&
{\mathfrak C}_l 
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0}^m
(B_{l+1}-A_{l+1}-(m+1))^{(\eta-\xi_1)} \cdot \binom{m}{\xi_1}
\cdot
\underline{(j_{l+1}+A_{l+1})^{(m+1+\xi_1)}} \tag{3b}
\end{eqnarray}
Now we decompose the doubly underlined term by using $(3b)$ repeatedly. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{1 \le j_1 < j_2 <  \cdots < j_l < j_{l+1} }
\prod\limits_{\eta=0}^l
(j_{\eta+1} + A_{\eta+1})^{(m+1)}
(j_{\eta+1} + B_{\eta+1})^{(m)}
= \\
&&
\left.
\sum\limits_{\eta=1}^l
\sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{(2(l-\eta)+1)m+l-\eta}
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0}^m
\sum\limits_{\xi_2=0}^{m+1+\xi_1}
\Lambda^{(l,\eta)}_\xi \cdot
(B_{l+1}-A_{l+1}-(m+1))^{(\eta-\xi_1)} \cdot \binom{m}{\xi_1}
\cdot
(A_{l+1} - (A_\eta-(l-\eta+1)) - (m+l-\eta+2+\xi))^{(m+1+\xi_1-\xi_2)} \cdot \binom{m+1+\xi_1}{\xi_2}
\cdot
\underline{(j_{l+1} + A_\eta-(l-\eta+1))^{((m+l-\eta+2+\xi+\xi_2)}}
+ \right. \\
&&
{\mathfrak C}_l 
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0}^m
(B_{l+1}-A_{l+1}-(m+1))^{(\eta-\xi_1)} \cdot \binom{m}{\xi_1}
\cdot
\underline{(j_{l+1}+A_{l+1})^{(m+1+\xi_1)}} \tag{3c}
\end{eqnarray}
Now we do the sum over $j_{l+1} = 1,\cdots, l$ by using the identity
$ \sum\limits_{j=1}^k (j + A)^{(m)} = ((k+A)^{(m+1)} - A^{(m+1)})/(m+1)$. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{1 \le j_1 < j_2 <  \cdots < j_l < j_{l+1} \le k}
\prod\limits_{\eta=0}^l
(j_{\eta+1} + A_{\eta+1})^{(m+1)}
(j_{\eta+1} + B_{\eta+1})^{(m)}
= \\
&&
\left.
\sum\limits_{\eta=1}^l
\sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{(2(l-\eta)+1)m+l-\eta}
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0}^m
\sum\limits_{\xi_2=0}^{m+1+\xi_1}
\Lambda^{(l,\eta)}_\xi \cdot
(B_{l+1}-A_{l+1}-(m+1))^{(\eta-\xi_1)} \cdot \binom{m}{\xi_1}
\cdot
(A_{l+1} - (A_\eta-(l-\eta+1)) - (m+l-\eta+2+\xi))^{(m+1+\xi_1-\xi_2)} \cdot \binom{m+1+\xi_1}{\xi_2}
\cdot
%
%\underline{(j_{l+1} + A_\eta-(l-\eta+1))^{((m+l-\eta+2+\xi+\xi_2)}}
\frac{(k+A_\eta-(l-\eta+1))^{(m+l-\eta+3+\xi+\xi_2)} - (A_\eta-(l-\eta+1))^{(m+l-\eta+3+\xi+\xi_2)}}{m+l-\eta+3+\xi+\xi_2}
%
+ \right. \\
&&
{\mathfrak C}_l 
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0}^m
(B_{l+1}-A_{l+1}-(m+1))^{(\eta-\xi_1)} \cdot \binom{m}{\xi_1}
\cdot
%
%\underline{(j_{l+1}+A_{l+1})^{(m+1+\xi_1)}} 
%
\frac{(k+A_{l+1})^{(m+2+\xi_1)} - (A_{l+1})^{(m+2+\xi_1)}}{m+2+\xi_1} \tag{3d}
\end{eqnarray}
Now we simplify. We firstly move the sum over $\xi_1$ to the very right (to the very bottom of the nested multiple sum) and then we substitute $\xi+\xi_2 \rightarrow \xi$. This yields:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{1 \le j_1 < j_2 <  \cdots < j_l < j_{l+1} \le k}
\prod\limits_{\eta=0}^l
(j_{\eta+1} + A_{\eta+1})^{(m+1)}
(j_{\eta+1} + B_{\eta+1})^{(m)}
= \\
&& \left.
\sum\limits_{\eta=1}^l
\sum\limits_{\xi=0}^{(2(l+1-\eta)+1)m+l+1-\eta} \right. \\
&& \left.
\left(
%
\left(
\sum\limits_{\xi_2=0 \vee((2(l-\eta)+1)m+l-\eta)}^{(2m+1) \wedge \xi}
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0 \vee (\xi_2-m-1)}^m
\Lambda^{(l,\eta)}_{\xi-\xi_2}
\cdot
%
(B_{l+1}-A_{l+1} -(m+1))^{(m-\xi_1)} \binom{m}{\xi_1}
\cdot
(A_{l+1}-(A_\eta-(l-\eta+1)) - (m+l-\eta+2+\xi-\xi_2))^{(m+1+\xi_1-\xi_2)} \binom{m+1+\xi_1}{\xi_2}
\right)
\cdot 
\frac{
(k+A_\eta-(l-\eta+1))^{(m+(l-\eta+3)+\xi)}
-
(A_\eta-(l-\eta+1))^{(m+(l-\eta+3)+\xi)}
}{m+l-\eta+3+\xi}
%
%
\right) +\right. \\
&&
{\mathfrak C}_l 
\sum\limits_{\xi_1=0}^m
(B_{l+1}-A_{l+1}-(m+1))^{(\eta-\xi_1)} \cdot \binom{m}{\xi_1}
\cdot
\frac{(k+A_{l+1})^{(m+2+\xi_1)} - (A_{l+1})^{(m+2+\xi_1)}}{m+2+\xi_1} \tag{3e}
\end{eqnarray}
Now we notice that the term in the last, single, sum is equal to the term in the double sum above it at $\eta = l+1$. As such we absorb the last single sum  into the double sum above it at $\eta = l+1$.
Then we see that the right hand side of the equality above has the same functional form as the conjecture $(2)$being evaluated at $l \rightarrow l+1$ with the new coefficients $\Lambda^{(l+1,\eta)}_\xi$ being given by $(2a)$. This completes the proof.

Below we verify the result numerically:
(*Checking the final result.*)
lmax = 4; kmax = 10; m = 2;(*m=1,2,3*)
Clear[Lambda, k];

Lambda = Table[
   0, {l, 1, lmax}, {\[Eta], 1, l}, {\[Xi], 
    0, (2 (l - \[Eta]) + 1) m + l - \[Eta]}];
Lambda[[1, 1]] = 
  Table[(up[Subscript[B, 1] - Subscript[A, 1] - (m + 1), 
     m - \[Xi]] Binomial[m, \[Xi]])/(m + 2 + \[Xi]), {\[Xi], 0, m}];

Do[
  Cl = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Eta] = 1\), \(l\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Xi] = 
       0\), \(\((2 \((l - \[Eta])\) + 1)\) m + 
       l - \[Eta]\)]\((\(-1\))\) Lambda[\([l, \[Eta], \ 
        1 + \[Xi]]\)] up[\((
\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(\[Eta]\)] - \((l - \[Eta])\))\), \((m + \((l \
- \[Eta] + 2)\) + \[Xi])\)]\)\);
  Lambda[[l + 1, \[Eta], 1 + \[Xi]]] = If[\[Eta] <= l, (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Xi]2 = 
         Max[0, \[Xi] - \((\((2 \((l - \[Eta])\) + 1)\) m + 
             l - \[Eta])\)]\), \(Min[\((2  m + 1)\), \[Xi]]\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Xi]1 = 
          
          Max[0, \[Xi]2 - m - 1]\), \(m\)]Lambda[\([l, \[Eta], 
           1 + \[Xi] - \[Xi]2]\)] \((up[
\*SubscriptBox[\(B\), \(l + 1\)] - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(l + 1\)] - \((m + 1)\), m - \[Xi]1])\) \((up[
\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(l + 1\)] - \((
\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(\[Eta]\)])\) - \((m + \[Xi] - \[Xi]2)\) - 
             1, \((m + 1 + \[Xi]1)\) - \[Xi]2] Binomial[\((m + 
              1 + \[Xi]1)\), \[Xi]2] Binomial[m, \[Xi]1])\)\)\)), 
     Cl up[Subscript[B, l + 1] - Subscript[A, l + 1] - (m + 1), 
       m - \[Xi]] Binomial[m, \[Xi]]] 1/(m + (l - \[Eta] + 3) + \[Xi]);
  , {l, 1, lmax - 1}, {\[Eta], 1, l + 1}, {\[Xi], 
   0, (2 (l + 1 - \[Eta]) + 1) m + l + 1 - \[Eta]}];
l = lmax - 1;
Print["l,m=", {l, m}];
(*Closed form expression--fast*)
ex1 = Table[Expand[(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Eta] = 1\), \(l\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Xi] = 
          0\), \(\((2 \((l - \[Eta])\) + 1)\) m + 
          l - \[Eta]\)]Lambda[\([l, \[Eta], 
           1 + \[Xi]]\)] \((up[\((k + 1 + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(\[Eta]\)] - \((l - \[Eta] + 
               1)\))\), \((m + \((l - \[Eta] + 
               2)\) + \[Xi])\)])\)\)\) + Cl)], {k, 1, kmax}];
(*From definition--slow*)
ex2 = Table[Sum[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(\[Eta] = 0\), \(l - 1\)]\(up[\((
\*SubscriptBox[\(j\), \(\[Eta] + 1\)] + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(\[Eta] + 1\)])\), \((m + 1)\)] up[\((
\*SubscriptBox[\(j\), \(\[Eta] + 1\)] + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(B\), \(\[Eta] + 1\)])\), m]\)\), 
    Evaluate[
     Sequence @@ 
      Table[{Subscript[j, \[Eta]], 
        If[\[Eta] == 1, 0, Subscript[j, \[Eta] - 1]] + 1, k}, {\[Eta],
         1, l}]]], {k, 1, kmax}];
(ex1 - ex2) // Expand

During evaluation of In[328]:= l,m={3,2}

Out[336]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}


Having said all this my question would be whether it is possible to derive the result $(2)$ using a combinatorial approach?
